# How to Get Spinner Selected Item

Tags: android

i just try to make a simple offline currency converter using 2 spinner.

i want to make an "if" function using the values of the spinner's selected item like below

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> isispinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.nilai_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    isispinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(isispinner);
    spinner1.setAdapter(isispinner);

    hitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  Object item1 = spinner.getSelectedItem();
  Object item2 = spinner1.getSelectedItem();

  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if ("IDR".equals(item1) && "USD".equals(item2)) {
                    ubahIDRtoUSD();
                }

                if ("USD".equals(item1) && "IDR".equals(item2)){
                    ubahUSDtoIDR();
                }
        }
    });

}
```

it's not working LOL .. am i doing it wrong or i'm missing something XD ??

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you try to get the selected item before it gets selected (i.e. outside the `onClick()` method. Try this way:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

Object item1 = spinner.getSelectedItem();
Object item2 = spinner1.getSelectedItem();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if ("IDR".equals(item1) && "USD".equals(item2)) {
                ubahIDRtoUSD();
            }

            if ("USD".equals(item1) && "IDR".equals(item2)){
                ubahUSDtoIDR();
            }
    }
});
```

}

And the `getSelectedItem()` method doesn't return `String` afaik, so comparing it to a `String` ("IRD") doesn't make sense.

Btw, there's a [full tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) on how to set a spinner.